# Как объявить двумерный массив, индексируемый парой число-строка?

Tags: c#, массивы, структуры

Например, чтобы можно было выполнить вызов вида `array[14, "word"]`.

Можно создать массив с элементами `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, но это уже будет не так удобно.

Возможно, это можно найти в интернете, но я не могу составить правильный запрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные массивы в C# невозможны. В них нет необходимости, поскольку язык имеет статическую типизацию, при этом существует большое количество обобщенных контейнеров практически на любой вкус. Массивы в C# индексируются целочисленными значениями. Для ключей других типов существуют  такие типы данных, как **Dictionary<T, U>**, **Lookup<T, U>**, **KeyValuePair<T, U>**, отчасти **Tuple<T, U>**. 
Сходного поведения можно достигнуть различными способами, в частности, так:

```
ar arr = new Dictionary<string, string>[5];
...
arr[0]["qwerty"] = "foo";
```

Однако с помощью индексаторов можно реализовать и аналогичный синтаксис (вопрос только, зачем):

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Dictionary<string, string>> dt = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    public string this[int first, string second]        
    {
        get { return data[first][second]; }
    }
}

....

var foo = new Foo();
string str = foo[0, "qwerty"];
```